# R: Name a data.frame after a value in a vector

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, dataframe

I am trying to create a data.frame within a for loop. I want to name the data.frame after whatever the value is in the vector for that iteration of the loop.

The vector comes from the `City` column in the `State` data.frame:

```
State

City  Zip
A     1  
B     2
C     3
```

What I have tried:

```
for( i in State$City){

i <- data.frame(sub=character(),street=character())
}
```

This will name the data.frame `i` not the value in the vector.

```
i

sub   street
```

If it was the first iteration in the loop then I would want the name of the data.frame to be  `A`

```
A

sub   street
```

If second iteration then `B`

If third iteration then `C`

Any help will be appreciated please let me know if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. Use `assign`

```
State = as.data.frame(list(City = c("A","B","C"),
                           ZIP = 1:3))
for( i in State$City){
  assign(i, data.frame(sub=character(),street=character()))
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why you got a down vote your answer worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @Dre It likely was down voted because `assign` is widely considered very bad practice. Trust me, you will be sorry down the road.

Comment: I never use `assign` myself either. The named list from @joran is likely a better method.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this in R is to keep things in a named list:

```
dat_list <- replicate(3,data.frame(sub=character(),street=character()),simplify = FALSE)
dat_list <- setNames(dat_list,c('A','B','C'))
```

I used `c('A','B','C')` rather than `State$City` just to make the code in my answer self contained and runnable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I would like to use it but I am having an issue with it. When I try your method I get  `dat_list` as a list of `3`. If I want make each list a data.frame then I have to do `A <- as.data.frame(dat_list$A).

Comment: @Dre Actually, no. The result is a list of three data frames, which is the whole point. The object `dat_list$A` is already a data frame. (We'll ignore the technical detail that data frames are themselves just a particular type of list.)